# Copy form External Workbook XLDOWN into Current workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy all the results from cell "A9" tell the end of the data using XLDOWN from  the the file named "DDR" & tab named "everett" and paste it back into the workbook im currently using.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

```
Sub XLDOWN1()
'
' XLDOWN1 Macro
'

'
    Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbDest As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rngSource As Range, rngDest As Range

    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("G:\GAGC\Accounting\Payroll\Payroll\Analysis Macro Upload\DDR.xlsx", , True)
    Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("Everett")


    ws.Range("A9", Range("A9").End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy



    Set rngSource = wsSource.Range("A9").Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))
    Set wbDest = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsDest = wbDest.Worksheets("2016")
    Set rngDest = wsDest.Range("A4") 'Destination Cell

    rngDest.Value = rngSource.Value 'Copies values over only

    wbSource.Close (False) 'Close without saving changes


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot. There were a few issues in the code you provided that should be clear after seeing the refactored code below.

```
Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbDest As Workbook
Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
Dim rngSource As Range, rngDest As Range

'set up source workbook, sheet, range
Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("G:\GAGC\Accounting\Payroll\Payroll\Analysis Macro Upload\DDR.xlsx", , True)
Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("Everett")
Set rngSource = wsSource.Range(wsSource.Range("A9"), wsSource.Range("A9").End(xlDown))

'set up destination workbook, sheet, range
Set wbDest = ThisWorkbook
Set wsDest = wbDest.Worksheets("2016")
Set rngDest = wsDest.Range("A4") 'Destination Cell

rngSource.Copy Destination:=rngDest

wbSource.Close False
```